# Android Error inflating class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, inflate

Recently I've added ActionBarSherlock to my android project. After adding it and testing application on AVD version 4.1 everything was fine, but launching application at 2.3.3 gives the next type of errors when starting activity at setContentView:

```
> 04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fitness.calculator/com.fitness.calculator.ProportionsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:1045)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:915)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:849)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:229)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.fitness.calculator.MainMenuActivity.onCreate(MainMenuActivity.java:45)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.fitness.calculator.ProportionsActivity.onCreate(ProportionsActivity.java:90)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  ... 11 more
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  ... 24 more
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.setBackground
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(ActionBarContainer.java:58)
04-05 18:55:03.277: E/AndroidRuntime(659):  ... 27 more
```

Does anybody have an idea what could cause that type of error? Any ideas? I can't find a solution for this problem.

Comment: seems you have exception in XML resource file at line no 26. Could just check what is there at line no. 26. Probably there would be a layout file for ActionBarContainer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by re-adding clear ActionBarSherlock library. First time I have fixed all warnings in library, and that caused the problem. So don't try to fix warnings in ActionBarSherlock. Hope this will help somebody.